# Grid Recyclerview gone item and there is a blank cell between two items

Tags: android

I'm using a Grid recyclerview for divide column. When I set visibility of an item to Gone,i have a blank cell between two items.
I don't want using remove item at position, just wanna set visibility for this item.
Please check image: [UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbC3T.png)
When I hide no2, no3 layout should be move to no2. No5 and No6 the same.
That is code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final FeedItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
           boolean ad = item.get(position);
            setVisibility(holder.itemView, ad);
            break;

    }
}
public void setVisibility(View view, boolean isVisible) {
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    if (isVisible) {
        int margin = (int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.feed_card_margin);
        params.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        params.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        params.height = 0;
        params.width = 0;
    }
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Any suggestion for this case? 
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, please add some code and a few screenshots of the program, current behavior and expected behavior. Are you trying to delete the item or hide it?

Comment: Probably it won't be possible using grid since the item is still present in the list it will keep an empty space since there is nothing to display. You should try StaggeredGridLayoutManager ..

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this with change visibility . instead you must delete item and i'm suggest to store removed item two new list to restore it when you need it.

For remove use this

```
public void removeAt(int position) {
      //try to store this item
      mDataset.remove(position);
      notifyItemRemoved(position);
      notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mDataSet.size());
  }
```

Comment: I agree with most of this answer (that removing the item from the adapter is the right way to get the behavior the OP wants), but there is no need to call notifyItemRangeChanged if you have implemented your adapter correctly. Doing so will only cause needless rebinding of every item after the removed one.